# Adding settings to Settings

Tags: android

The application I am developing is in large parts a background-only Service BUT requires some settings that the user must add. Is there a way to integrate applications with the common Settings application/view/activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to integrate
>   applications with the common Settings
>   application/view/activity?

Only by modifying the firmware. Android does not support SDK applications defining or adding global preferences.

You can use the same look and feel for your own settings activity by use of `PreferenceActivity` and preference XML files. But you will then still need to have that activity appear in the Launcher.

Comment: Actually that isn't 100% true. TTS engines do that all the time without modifying firmware and without requiring root access. I just don't know [how](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12096555/636571) they do it.

Comment: @an00b: "TTS engines do that all the time" -- strictly speaking, they do not. They can publish their own settings activity, that the Settings app can elect to link to. That is not possible for arbitrary apps, as per the OP.

Comment: OK but how do they get the Settings app to elect to link to? What protocol/api/hook is being used to make their settings activity invokable from the System Settings? I am currently researching this and I have no clue where to begin: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12096555/636571