# How to add own VPN settings using Java Reflecion (Android SDK 14+)

Tags: java, android, vpn

I know that android.net.VpnService is basically a base class to build custom vpn solutions, but all I want is to create and use PPTP or L2TP VPN connection (just a new profile for built-in VPN manager).
I think that the easiest way to do that is to use Java reflection for com.android.settings.vpn.VpnSettings. Here's the code snippet for that from the other post ([How to add own VPN settings to system VPN settings page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446661/how-to-add-own-vpn-settings-to-system-vpn-settings-page))

```
package com.nikola.despotoski.whatever;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class VpnSetter {

    private static Map<String , Class<?>> getMappedFields(){
        Map<String , Class<?>> fieldsAndTypes = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
        fieldsAndTypes.put("name", String.class);        // 0
        fieldsAndTypes.put("type" , int.class);   // 1
        fieldsAndTypes.put("server", String.class);        // 2
        fieldsAndTypes.put("username", String.class);
        fieldsAndTypes.put("password", String.class);
        fieldsAndTypes.put("dnsServers", String.class);
        fieldsAndTypes.put("searchDomains", String.class);
        fieldsAndTypes.put("routes", String.class);
        fieldsAndTypes.put("mppe", boolean.class);
        fieldsAndTypes.put("l2tpSecret", String.class);
        fieldsAndTypes.put("ipsecIdentifier", String.class);
        fieldsAndTypes.put("ipsecSecret", String.class);
        fieldsAndTypes.put("ipsecUserCert", String.class);
        fieldsAndTypes.put("ipsecCaCert", String.class);
        fieldsAndTypes.put("saveLogin", boolean.class);
        return fieldsAndTypes;
    }
    public static final Set<String> VPN_PROFILE_KEYS = getMappedFields().keySet(); // contains keys for quicker generation of key-value map for each 

    public static void addVpnProfile(String vpnProfileKey, Map<String, Object> values) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException{
        Class<?> vpnSettings = Class.forName("com.android.settings.vpn2.VpnSettings");
        Class<?>[] privateVpnSettingsClasses = vpnSettings.getDeclaredClasses();
        Class<?> vpnPreference = null;
        Class<?> vpnProfileClass = Class.forName("com.android.settings.vpn2.VpnProfile");
        for(Class<?> priv :privateVpnSettingsClasses ){
            if(priv.getName().equals("VpnPreference")){
                vpnPreference = priv;
                break;
            }
        }
        Field vpnProfileFromVpnPreferenceField = vpnPreference.getDeclaredField("mProfile");
        vpnProfileFromVpnPreferenceField.setAccessible(true);
        Object vpnProfile = vpnProfileFromVpnPreferenceField.get(vpnProfileClass);
        Constructor<?> constructor = vpnProfileFromVpnPreferenceField.getClass().getConstructors()[0];
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        vpnProfile = constructor.newInstance(vpnProfileKey);//creating new instance of VpnProfile class
        Map<String, Class<?>> vpnProfileMap = getMappedFields();
        Iterator<String> profileKeysIterator = vpnProfileMap.keySet().iterator();
        while(profileKeysIterator.hasNext()){
            String key = profileKeysIterator.next();
            Field field = vpnProfile.getClass().getField(key);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if(vpnProfileMap.get(key).equals(String.class) && values.get(key)!=null){
                String s = new String();
                field.set(s, "value");//change this
            }else if(vpnProfileMap.get(key).equals(boolean.class) && values.get(key)!=null){
                int i = 0;
                field.setInt(i, 1111111);// change this
            }else if(values.get(key)!=null){
                boolean  b = false;
                field.setBoolean(b, true);// change this
            }

        }
        vpnSettings = Class.forName("com.android.settings.vpn.VpnSettings"); //time to add it to settings
        Method addProfileMethod = vpnSettings.getDeclaredMethod("addProfile", vpnProfile.getClass()); 
        addProfileMethod.setAccessible(true);
        addProfileMethod.invoke(vpnSettings, vpnProfile);
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get: `java.lang.classnotfoundexception: com.android.settings.vpn2.vpnsettings`

Just what to know what I'm doing wrong. I tried with API 14, 15 .. 18 **Device is not rooted.**

If you have another suggestion how to add a new profile to built-in VPN manager please let me know.

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator? I believe that the VPN-related artifacts (such as VpnService) aren't included in the emulator. Could you try using a physical device running 4.0 or later?

Comment: no, I'm testing on a real device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, what you're trying isn't going to work because the `VpnSettings` class is not available within your app. It's not a private part of the Android framework; it's part of the Settings app, which is a completely separate app from yours. It's like trying to access the `org.mozilla.firefox.App` class from the Firefox app. You can't do it. And if you could, you'd find that it still wouldn't work, because `VpnSettings` saves its settings to a location that your app doesn't have permission to access.

If your device **was** rooted, and your app had root access, you could potentially write to that location yourself. Otherwise, you have no chance at this.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that changing my Android Project Build Target to the Google APIs target instead of just the Android target has fixed the issue (or at least I no longer get the ClassNotFoundException any longer).

Try setting this yourself: Right click on your project. Build Path -> Configure Build Path… Go to the Android settings in the left pane. Check the corresponding Google APIs target for your project.

EDIT: This fixed the `VpnProfile` issue I had, but not the `VpnSettings` that you're having (now I'm having that issue).

EDIT 2: VpnSettings class is located in the Settings app. You can download the source for the Settings app if you'd like: `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings.git`

Comment: can't test it right now, have you tried this? Does it work for you?